# How to get text from material design TextInputLayout correctly?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I want to get a text from the material design's TextInputLayout using a custom end Icon.

I tried to do that:

```java
TextInputLayout textInputCustomEndIcon = findViewById(R.id.editText);
final TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(textInputCustomEndIcon.getContext());
    
textInputCustomEndIcon.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (editText.getText() != null) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
    
            Log.i("MainActivity", "setEndIconOnClickListener:"+ text);
        }
    }
});
```

But I get an empty text, not null but empty!!

Comment: Do you have a `<TextInputEditText>` in the `<TextInputLayout>` in your layout XML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using something like that:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_end_icon"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       ../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Just use:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.custom_end_icon);
String text = textInputLayout.getEditText().getText();
```

**Your issue** is here:

```
final TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(textInputCustomEndIcon.getContext());
```

You are only creating a new instance of `TextInputEditText`, it isn't the `TextInputEditText` inside the `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Is there a way to get/access the `TextInputLayout` of a `TextInputEditText` that's "inside" said `TextInputLayout`, something like `editText.getTextInputLayout`?

Comment: getText() returns Editable. You have to call getText().toString(). I don't know why you use getEditText() on the Layout. I use the TextInputEditText directly: ((TextInputEditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.etTheText)).getText().toString().

Comment: In my case, I was using `view` input argument to `OnClick()` method. But, when I changed `view.findViewById(R.id.input)` to `getView().findViewById(R.id.input_recipient)` everything works like a charm. After that, I get my text with `getView().findViewById(R.id.input_recipient).getText().toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. I just solved it this way. In the String variable I need to validate that the data has been correctly inserted with **.trim()**

```java
  String vname=Name.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: You don't validate anything. You just trim your String.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, you can't just use `String text = textInputLayout.getEditText().getText();` to get the text value from the `TextInputEditText`.
You need to convert it to `Editable` or wrap it using `String.valueOf()` if you gonna wrap it as a `String`, like this:

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/edt_title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/request_title"
android:inputType="textCapWords"
android:maxLength="255" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Java**

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.edt_title);

String strTitle = String.valueOf(textInputLayout.getEditText().getText());
```

or

```
Editable strTitle = textInputLayout.getEditText().getText();
```

Then you can use both above as a string like this

```
Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this, strTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You can also use `toString()` method on Editable object, because documentation of this method said:  `Return a String containing a copy of the chars in this buffer.`. I don't know why but my version of material library does not contain `getEditText()` method but `getEditableText()` I think they doing the same thing (returning Editable). Material lib version: `1.1.0`

Comment: toString() woked for me. In kotlin use: `binding.myTextInputEditText.text.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

First Activity:

```
String uname = userV.getEditText().getText().toString();
    
Intent intent1 = new Intent(VolunteerActivity.this, VolunteerView.class);
intent1.putExtra("USER_NAME", uname);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Second Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) 
{
    String uname = extras.getString("USER_NAME");
    tv2.setText(uname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**, I was having the same problem while getting text from **TextInputEditText** and this is the solution I applied:

```kotlin
private lateinit var emailForAuthentication : TextInputEditText
private lateinit var passwordForAuthentication : TextInputEditText

emailForAuthentication = findViewById(R.id.emailedittext)

val email = emailForAuthentication.editableText
val password = passwordForAuthentication.editableText

Log.d("login","$email")
```

**Explaination:**  By wrapping the **Editable Type** variable in the String, I am able to showcase the text from the **TextInputEditText** without getting an empty String.

**Note:**  I am not getting a reference from **TextInputLayout** like in previous answers but I am using **TextInputEditText** to get a reference.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        style="?attr/textInputFilledStyle"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/mailicon"
        app:endIconContentDescription="mail icon"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="50dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="50dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="50dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="50dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/emailedittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get text or print in toast heres the simple way

```
TextInputLayout editext_usr_sign;

editext_usr_sign = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usr);

String a = editext_usr_sign.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

Toast.makeText(Registration.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```